# Background service

Tags: android, service, background

I want to create a little app, which logs data in the background. So I try it whit a bound service. This works fine but if i close the app the service stops too.
So, my question: Is it a good way to perform that with a instant service?
And how can I keep the service running in the background when app is closend (i want to start it after boot too)?

Comment: Bound services should only run while there is some component of your app running. You need to use a "started" service as it is named in http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public class ServiceBackground extends Service {


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind( final Intent arg0 ) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor( 1 ); // Number of threads keep in the pool

        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate( new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Log.i( "LocalService", "service running" );

                if (stopCondition == true ) {
                    executor.shutdownNow();
                }

            }
        }, 1, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand( final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId ) {
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

Remember to register the service in AndroidManifest.xml

More information about [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Starting the service

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( final Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        this.setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

        this.startService( new Intent( this, ServiceBackground.class ) );

    }

}
```

Comment: I am trying this method out for a periodic task, but it does not seem to work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872016/scheduledthreadpoolexecutor-for-a-periodic-task-using-retrofit-just-firing-onc

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this link](http://devescape.blogspot.com/2011/02/persistent-services-in-android.html) on system applications.

If the app is not a system app, Android can destroy the process in a low-memory situation, this includes services. Otherwise checkout the [startForeground()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) for application services.