# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor only "ticking" once

Tags: android, runnable

I was using a `CountDownTimer` for some countdown functionality I have in my `Activity`.  I decided to move away from `CountDownTimer` and use `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` because `CountDownTimer`s can't cancel themselves in `onTick()`.

For some reason, my `Runnable` in the following code only executes once.  I'm not sure why it isn't executing multiple times.  The `destroyCountdownTimer()` function is not getting hit.

```
private ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor mCountdownTimer;
private Tick mTick;

class Tick implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.e("tick", String.valueOf(mAccumulatedMilliseconds));
        mAccumulatedMilliseconds += 1000;
        populateTimeAccumulated();
        populateTimeRemaining();
        updatePercentages();

        if (mTotalMilliseconds <= mAccumulatedMilliseconds) {
            destroyCountdownTimer();
        }
    }
}

private void startCountdown() {
    if (mAccumulatedMilliseconds < mTotalMilliseconds) {
        mCounterIsRunning = true;

        if (mCountdownTimer == null) {
            mCountdownTimer = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
        }

        if (mTick == null) {
            mTick = new Tick();
        }

        mCountdownTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mTick, 1000, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}

private void destroyCountdownTimer() {
    if (mCountdownTimer != null) {
        mCountdownTimer.shutdownNow();
        mCountdownTimer = null;
    }

    if (mTick != null) {
        mTick = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add logging to your cancellation logic (or if you must, use the breakpoint debugger) and see if that is triggering.

Comment: I've set a breakpoint in the call to destroy the timer.  It is not being hit.  After commenting out the populate/update calls inside the `Runnable`, everything is working fine.  I see no reason why any of them should be holding up the `Runnable`.  They were all functioning perfectly fine when I was using a `CountDownTimer`. I will update the main post with the code inside of them in a moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) says:

```
If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed.
```

Add try-catch block to your Tick runnable.

Comment: There is an exception inside `populateTimeAccumulated()`.

Comment: 04-08 13:24:03.609: E/Tick(2722): error: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: Do I need to pass a pointer to the `Activity` to the `Runnable` or something?

Comment: Need to make all actions with view in UI thread. For that you can use [runOnUiThread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254523/android-runonuithread-explanation) method of Activity - do everything inside its runnable.